# Does music ID from media provider change when it's file is moved?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-mediascanner

We have this file `/sdcard/music/file.mp3` and it's corresponding ID in the `MediaStore` is `1`. Will the ID change when:

- the file is moved, say moved to `/sdcard/music2/file.mp3`
- the file is renamed (might be the same as above)

After the media scanner has finished re-scanning?

**Update for clarification and so you can see my purpose.**

Although below is actually not my real purpose but the idea is the same:

I would like to associate each mp3 file with a URL (say its lyrics). I would save it in my own sqlite database. My sqlite database will have ID and URL columns where the ID column is the same ID in the media provider.

Comment: Basically the media manager doesn't public that information. So you shouldn't rely on it to do your jobs.

Comment: the row ID field is public and why won't we rely on it? we can use the id to map instead of creating our own database ID..

Comment: I think the ID field is used to distinguish different items. But the answer you're asking for is not available in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late for an answer. **Yes, it'll change.** When you rename or move a file, the media provider acts the same as if you deleted the file and then created it again. It's handled like a totally different file.

However, even though I'm not aware of your real purpose, I still think you could use MediaStore. IF it's okay for you, let me in on how you intend to use it, so I can help you sort this out.

Comment: Hello, I know this question is old, but I am in this exact scenario. How do we reference songs/playlists/albums/artists/genres if they have no stable identifier in MediaStore?

Comment: @Alex see Note at the end of [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-item) section. They have mentioned that files can be moved by updating its `RELATIVE_PATH` or `DISPLAY_NAME`. In this case file is moved, but its `_ID` is not updated!!